# How to create a dynamic UI with Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

create widget at runtime as texts and buttons, with kotlin language

For example, when clicking a button, a new text is created

Comment: XML or Compose?

Answer (score -1):

- lets assume you have a `ViewGroup` such as `LinearLayout` and lets name it `group`
- and you have a button.

Based on this assumption. I would do the following

```
mButton.setOnClickListener{
    group.addView(TextView(context)
       .also{
           it.text = "your text"
          })
}
```

of course you will have to work on positioning it too